# How can I parse a RTF string to JSX or HTML

Tags: reactjs, rtf, draftjs

I have a rtf string format that looks like this.

`{\\rtf1\\ansi\\b hi there\\b0}`

How can I parse this in react/javascript for it become like this:

`<p><strong>hi there</strong></p>`

I have already tried using draft.js but It seems i cannot parse the format I have mentioned above. I also tried using regEx, but I seems its not that reliable I have other rtf formats that seems quite complicated. I want this to be in html format or just a simple clean plain text/string.

I also checked `rtf2html` package but, it seems to be a standalone tool.

My situation is the rtf string is coming from an api. and I need to parse it to make it visible in my app.

Comment: check this package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/rtf2html

Comment: I checked that package before but, it is a standalone tool. My situation is the rtf string is coming from an api. and I need to parse it to make it visible in my app. @SmitVora

Comment: you can first get rft string from api then use this js: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Novlr/rtf2html/master/index.js  to convert it into html string ,then set it in state .after that show that state variable to div: like :
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: stateVariable}} />

Comment: how can I install that package in my react app? @SmitVora

Comment: you don't need to install,just include in public/index.html's head.

Comment: after I put in in the public/index.html head, how can I use it inside my component? Sorry, but I can't find any documentation regarding about this. @SmitVora

Comment: you can use it like this example : https://npm.runkit.com/rtf2html

var rtf2html = require("rtf2html");

console.log(rtf2html("{\\rtf1\\ansi\\b hi there\\b0}"))

Comment: thank you very much!